# Unintended sliding blocks Unity (5) physics

Tags: unity, physics

A game I'm working on right now relies on the Unity physics system for collisions, gravity etc. This all works well except for one strange thing. When an explosive is placed on a stone cube, it'll slide right off.

A video displaying the sliding behavior: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lr6lhnn30x61tvf/Unity%202015-02-19%2013-41-39-54.avi?dl=0

The stone gameobject settings: http://puu.sh/g3BFn/c15483b8ea.jpg The explosive has the same settings except for that the Mass is 1.

What could cause this weird sliding and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I belive there is no friction. Add a physic material with a friction.

Comment: I gave every single cube in the scene the following material: http://puu.sh/g54CK/bb2f6719e9.png and the explosive still slid out of the building.